# Why doesn't rake db:migrate report version number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dbmigrate

rake 0.8.7, rails/activerecord 2.3.3

Output from rake db:migrate:

==   CreateProducts: migrating =================================================
-- create_table(:products)
   -> 0.0017s
==   CreateProducts: migrated (0.0019s) ========================================

Shouldn't the version number, in this case 20090724013528, appear before the migration name?

Comment: To further clarify, the output from the rake db:migrate shown in Agile Web Development with Rails, Third Edition does include the version number:

== 20080601000001 CreateProducts: migrating ========================
-- create_table(:products)
-> 0.0027s
== 20080601000001 CreateProducts: migrated (0.0028s) ===============

I'm just trying to figure out if the output from the command has changed or if there's some other problem.

Answer (score 4):

I can't remember 100% but I think they removed the number in that output when they switch migrations over to the UTC timestamps.

You can however check the current version of your DB using:

```
rake db:version
```

Comment: Based on the output shown in the book I mentioned in the updated question, the version number was included at some point. Looking at the code for the announce method that generates the output it seems like the @version variable contains a blank rather than the version number.

Answer (score 1):

As [pointed out by paulsnotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180638/why-doesnt-rake-dbmigrate-report-version-number/1180692#1180692), the timestamp represents the version number. If you really want to switch back to sequential numbers, you can set a flag in environment.rb.

```
config.active_record.timestamped_migrations = false
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to switch back to sequential numbers.